# Nextjs, Help me solve a URL issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, app-router

I just started learning NextJS 13 App route, I'm a bit confused about URLs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlQ16.png)

structure folder:

```
app
    products
            [slug]
                    page.tsx
components
    ProductCard.tsx
```

example:

```
// ProductCard.tsx

return (
    <div>
        <Link href={`/products/${prod.slug}`} />
    </div>
)

when click to Link then url is 'localhost:3000/products/car'

i want url is 'localhost:3000/car'

help me!
```

Answer (score 0):

As per looking at your question, you want your url to be

> i want url is 'localhost:3000/car'

And this is happening

> when click to Link then url is 'localhost:3000/products/car'

So as per what you need is
`href={/${prod.slug}}`

So you will get the url like

https://localhost:3000/whatever the sug contains

Comment: hi, thank bro, If I use `href={/${prod.slug}}` and the result will be 404 not found page, do you have another way?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the srtucture so you don't get 404:

```html
app
    [slug]
        page.tsx

components
    ProductCard.tsx
```

and edit your ProductCard.tsx:

```
// ProductCard.tsx

return (
    <div>
        <Link href={`/${prod.slug}`} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: To separate posts and products, you have to create the same structure as you said. And the links should be  <Link href={`/products/${prod.slug}`} /> (in ProductCard.tsx) and   <Link href={`/posts/${post.slug}`} /> (in PostCard.tsx).

Comment: <Link/> follows the page.tsx file. For localhost:3000/car you should have a structure like this: src/app/[slug]/page.tsx. According to the requirements that you want to create the post and product for you, this is not possible.It is better to separate it

Comment: you can create a path like app/[id]/product/[name]/page.tsx for products and a path like app/[id]/post/[name]/page.tsx

Comment: see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/next-14-0-3-forked-9kzh22?file=%2Fapp%2F%5BId%5D%2Fpost%2F%5BpostName%5D%2Fpage.tsx)

Comment: If you want to delete product and post from url, how do you want to distinguish between them.
Because this is not possible in dynamic routes, as a result of both links __<Link href={`/${productId}`} />__ and __<Link href={`/${postId}`}/>__ to __app/[slug]/page .tsx__ are sent. Now, on this page, how do you want to make a difference between post and product so that you can create the right ui and the right data based on them? So send their needs to different routes so that you can manage this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would structure your directory to achieve this URL `localhost:3000/car`

Have your directory structured in this way: `app/[slug]/page.tsx`

To access the URL, you will have to modify `ProductCard` as so:

```
// ProductCard.tsx

return (
    <div>
        <Link href={`/${prod.slug}`}>
          Click here
        </Link>
    </div>
)
```

Having `/product` as part of the URL, indicates that you are trying to access the product route `app/product/[slug]/page.tsx` instead of the root route `app/[slug]/page.tsx`

[Check more on how routing works in NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages)